# Iterate through spans using javascript

Tags: javascript

Using only Javascript, how can I iterate through every span id = "expiredDate"? I would think that this would be quite easy with a for each loop, but it doesn't appear to exist in javascript. My below code only works for the first element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var definedDate = window.document.getElementById('expiredDate').innerHTML.split("-");
    var expiredDate = new Date(definedDate[0], definedDate[1] - 1, definedDate[2]);
    var graceDate = new Date(definedDate[0], definedDate[1] - 1, definedDate[2] - 30);
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if(currentDate > expiredDate) {document.getElementById('expiredDate').style.color = '#cc6666';}
    else if(currentDate < expiredDate && currentDate > graceDate) {document.getElementById('expiredDate').style.color = '#f0c674';}
    else {document.getElementById('expiredDate').style.color = '#b5bd68';}
}
</script>
<span id="expiredDate">2013-01-01</span>
<span id="expiredDate">2014-01-01</span>
<span id="expiredDate">2015-01-01</span>
```

Comment: there should be only one `span` with an `id` of `expiredDate` if you want valid html.

Comment: @Kyle - Fair enough, can this be done with classes?

Comment: *should* be done with classes

Comment: @bswinnerton yes, it can and as Jason points out, should be done with classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch your IDs to classes and try the following

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var l = spans.length;
for (var i=0;i<l;i++) {
    var spanClass = spans[i].getAttribute("class"); 
    if ( spanClass === "expiredDate" ) { 
        /*do stuff to current spans[i] here*/
    }
}
```

Comment: The [class attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-class) is a space-separated list. What happens to your example if the span has class `expiredDate` and something else? To check if a class is part of the list, you should be looking for e.g. `(' ' + spanClass + ' ').indexOf(' ' + 'expiredDate' + ' ') !== -1;`

Answer (score 2):

Two methods not said yet; for both you should be using the form

```
<span class="expiredDate">...</span>
```

1. [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) method:

```
var result = document.querySelectorAll('span.expiredDate'); // NodeList
```

2. [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) combined with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var result = Array.prototype.filter.call(
                 document.getElementsByClassName('expiredDate'),
                 function (elm) { return elm.tagName === 'SPAN'; }
             ); // Array
```

---

Method 1 is faster, but because you're already iterating through them with method 2 you could save yourself a loop later by putting your desired actions inside the filter's function, therefore making it faster overall.

Comment: If I were to use method 1, would line 3 become: `var definedDate = document.querySelectorAll('span.expiredDate').innerHTML.split("-");`?

Comment: No, a [_NodeList_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) is almost the same as an _Array_, you'd loop over `result` using some loop variable, say `i`, and do `var definedDate = result[i].innerHTML.split("-");`

Comment: The 'save a loop' I was talking about in method 2 is, after establishing `elm.tagName === 'SPAN'` (i.e. use `if` not `return`), perform what you want with `elm`. It is very similar to Jason's way, except it is done _class then span_, rather than _span then class_.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which browser versions you are targeting. See caniuse's [document.getElementsByClassName](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname). Depending on your scope you could also use document.getElementsByTagName and iterate. Or use XPath or jQuery.